# how to add default option in select tag on ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Through `select_tag` i want to add a default option as  **select a category**

here is my code

```
<%= select_tag 'category', options_from_collection_for_select(@categories, 'id', 'name', :onchange => 'update_subscategories_div(this.value)'%>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `prompt` option of [***select_tag***](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/select_tag)

```
<%= select_tag 'category', options_from_collection_for_select(@categories, 'id', 'name'), prompt: "Select a Category", :onchange => 'update_subscategories_div(this.value)' %>
```